# How to check if user is in back end?

Tags: plugins, admin, user-access

In my application, i have one form.
Now if user is in front end i want to display the title but if he is in back end i do not want to  display it.

I do not want to check it based on user role.

Comment: This answer seems to address your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/343592/43252

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin). It checks if you're viewing an Admin page, means the backend.

Comment: will it work for other user like subscriber ?

Comment: Yep. It works for all roles.

Comment: How about loading a script on a specific admin page?

Comment: The action hook `admin_print_scripts` is meant to do that.

Comment: Of note, an ajax request will make this return TRUE.

Also, right in the documentation it says that this is not meant to be used as a security check.

Comment: This does not apply anymore to WordPress since Gutenberg. Now, all screens that use Gutenberg will return false when checking for is_admin. Same in the Customizer. And as well for when you are doing AJAX calls. `is_admin` is a misleading, abused function. You cannot use it to safely check if you are in an admin screen.
So, you can also not use it to check if you are in the front end, because during an AJAX call this function would return true, since the function does by definition `Determine whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.`
That is true in an ajax call.

Answer (score 20):

Use [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) to check if the the current page is an administration page. Despite its name this is not a user role check. It returns always `FALSE` on front end, no matter what role the user has.

Comment: False since the shitty blocks editor has been purged down the WP Community's throat: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47394
Since then, you can _not_ anymore safely define if you are moving around the admin, or the front end.

Comment: @BedaSchmid - What's the alternative to `is_admin`?

Comment: @Motivated there is none. You have to do a BUNCH of checks now, such as if it is during an ajax event, if it is some specific screen, if it is a block editing thing, if the user is logged in, if the user has cap... etc. This never was any different in terms of _security_ since is_admin does NOT check if the _user_ is somehow admin or not, but, at least it was able to tell you generically if it was an _admin area_ (unless during AJAX requests, which is always is_admin). The joke is, that blocks editors tell you is_admin FALSE, because it does not run "in the backend" but over REST.