# How to set up a private custom post type that is accessible in the administrative dashboard?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, admin, pre-get-posts

I'm not entirely sure of the best way to approach the requirement so I'm hoping someone who has more experience with it will be able to share some gems. I've set up a custom post type with the following settings;

- Public => True
- Publicly Queryable => True
- Has Archive => True
- Exclude from Search => False

The posts are intended to be private and accessible to any role that has the capability of `read_private_pages` and `read_private_posts`. Users have to be logged in to view the content.

I'm also using the action `pre_get_posts` to filter the the query for the custom post type. In researching the options with checking if the page is part of the administrative interface, it seems that `is_admin` isn't [reliable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45381/how-to-check-if-user-is-in-back-end).

If yes, what's the best way to configure the custom post type without `pre_get_posts` affecting any administrative queries?

Comment: Using `is_admin()` in `pre_get_posts` hooks has always worked perfectly for me. Gutenberg and AJAX do complicate its use, but to avoid impacting list tables it will work.

Comment: Since it's a custom post-type can you not just generate a template to specifically handle that post type, then check if users are logged in, and if they are, check if they have the correct capabilities, then display the content, and if they fail either of the conditions, show them fallback "you can't see this" content?  Most of what you're after, if I'm understanding correctly, is already handled by WP, so it's just a matter of determining when to display the content of the posts, vs. when to display a fallback message.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, as I'm creating a custom post type with 'Has archive' enabled, it's accessible with the desired slug e.g. `books`.  Since it's only meant to be accessible by roles with `read_private_pages` and `read_private_posts`, the first check is `if( ( is_post_type_archive( 'books') ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) { wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;`. It redirects the users to the login page. Since it's `read_private_pages` and `read_private_pages`, this natively allows `administrators` and `editors` to access the page. I've also granted it to `subscribers`.

Comment: The bit I'm unclear about is whether `if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {` is correct, since the aim is to only affect the query for that page with `pre_get_posts`. If I'm reading your comment correctly, it sounds like I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend, you can use `template_redirect` action to identify the page, and perform redirects or adjust the request on the fly (untested):

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    if ( ! is_singular( 'cpt' ) && ! is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( current_user_can( 'read_private_pages' ) || current_user_can( 'read_private_posts' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
} );
```

For excluding from search, you'll have to use `pre_get_posts` to prevent the posts form being listed in the results, unless you change `exclude_from_search` to `true` in the CPT registration.

Comment: I don't see how this achieves the requirement I shared. I've included additional background to my feedback to TonyDjukic.

Comment: It would prevent users without the capabilities from accessing the archive and singular pages, keeping them private.

Comment: why wouldn't you do something like `function dosomething() {
    if( ( is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' ) ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        exit;
    }

    if ( current_user_can( 'read_private_pages' ) || current_user_can( 'read_private_posts' ) ) {
        // Do something
    }
}`

Comment: Why 404 vs do a redirect? Mimicking behavior of a page that does not exist discourages unauthorized users from thinking the page does exist. Of course you could replace the 404 lines with a redirect if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go

```
function YOUR_POST_TYPE_force_type_private($post)
{
    if ($post['post_type'] == 'YOUR_POST_TYPE')
    $post['post_status'] = 'private';
    return $post;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_force_type_private');
```